# Character encoding when copying some text from somewhere to Emacs and saving to a file

Tags: files, copy-paste, character-encoding

Suppose I copy some text from a source (e.g. a webpage, a text file opened in an editor such as gedit or emacs) to a buffer in emacs, and then save the buffer to a text file.

1. **When I copy the text from the source to the Emacs buffer,**

   Do I actually copy "the code values of the text under the encoding
   method used by the source" to the Emacs buffer? Or do I copy
   something else of the text?

   Does emacs need to know the encoding method of the text in the
   source?

   Does conversion of encoding involve during this copy
   process?
2. **When Emacs writes the buffer to a text file,**

   by default, without customized configurations of emacs, will emacs
   write the buffer to the text file using the same encoding method as
   the source does?

Answer (score 6):

> When I copy the text from the source to the emacs buffer ...

What you copy depends upon the application you are copying from. Some applications release UTF-8 encoded strings while others use different [formats](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/CTEXT/ctext.html). Emacs uses the variable `selection-coding-system` to determine whether to decide the encoding from the data or presume a particular encoding. See the documentation of `selection-coding-system` for more details. Emacs has its own internal representation [`utf-8-emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Representations.html#Text-Representations), so any text insertion has an implicit conversion into this representation.

> When emacs write the buffer to a text file...

For an unconfigured emacs, I believe emacs uses `select-safe-coding-system` to determine a coding system or prompt the user if undecided. Here is an excerpt from the documentation of `select-safe-coding-system` that determines when emacs prompts for a coding system choice.

[Source](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/User_002dChosen-Coding-Systems.html#User_002dChosen-Coding-Systems) (Formatting mine)

> "If `default-coding-system` is non-nil, that is the first coding system to try; if that can handle the text, `select-safe-coding-system` returns that coding system. It can also be a list of coding systems; then the function tries each of them one by one. After trying all of them, it next tries the current buffer's value of `buffer-file-coding-system` (if it is not undecided), then the default value of `buffer-file-coding-system` and finally the user's most preferred coding system, which the user can set using the command `prefer-coding-system` (see Recognizing Coding Systems).
>
> If one of those coding systems can safely encode all the specified text, `select-safe-coding-system` chooses it and returns it. Otherwise, it asks the user to choose from a list of coding systems which can encode all the text, and returns the user's choice."