# Pasting Text from Clipboard - why ^M instead of linebreaks?

Tags: microsoft-windows, character-encoding, copy-paste, line-break, clipboard

I'm using some `VBA` scripts which copy Text in `MS Outlook` from an e-mail message and send it to the clipboard.

If I then paste the clipboard content with `Ctrl-Y` in `Emacs 24.5.1` in `Windows 7`, the linebreaks are missing and I see a red *^M* instead in my emacs buffer.

What can I do to directly insert linebreaks or convert the text in emacs to the "normal" encoding?

My current settings in my .emacs file are

```
;; file encoding utf-8 preferred
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8)
```

**However:** If I copy a text from an e-Mail in `MS Outlook` to the Clipboard with `Ctrl-C` and paste it in an emacs-buffer with `Ctrl-Y`, the linebreaks are ok.

Answer (score 5):

The linebreaks are missing because there is a conflict between your coding system on the desktop and your emacs setup. Emacs can be configured to have different coding systems for the terminal, keyboard and clipboard.

Try to set your clipboard coding system and selection coding system to `utf-16-le`, i.e.,:

```
(if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (progn
      (set-clipboard-coding-system 'utf-16-le)
      (set-selection-coding-system 'utf-16-le))
  (set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8))
(setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does not help but makes things even worse, as Umlauts are now also pasted as \xxx code (like \344 instead of ä).

Comment: Try setting `(setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))`

Comment: unfortunately, this does not help either. :( Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Combined with @aagaard 's solution. This worked for me:

```
(if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (progn
      (set-clipboard-coding-system 'utf-16-le)
      (set-selection-coding-system 'utf-16-le))
  (set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8))
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(set-language-environment "UTF-8")
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8-unix)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
;; Treat clipboard input as UTF-8 string first; compound text next, etc.
(when (display-graphic-p)
  (setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING)))
```

Full can be found [here](https://github.com/MatthewZMD/.emacs.d#utf-8-coding-system)

Comment: This worked for me in that when I copied the `^M` occurrences showed upon first pasting in to a file but if I saved file and then reopened they disappeared.  Any thoughts?