# copying into emacs from clipboard garbled

Tags: character-encoding

When I copy data from outside to my emacs, it is garbled

```
(venv)  tree ./scripts
scripts
├── foo.sh
├── bar.sh
├── start.sh
├── stop.py
```

However, when I paste this in emacs, I get this:

```
(venv)  tree ./scripts
scripts
\u251c\u2500\u2500 foo.sh
\u251c\u2500\u2500 bar.sh
\u251c\u2500\u2500 start.sh
\u251c\u2500\u2500 stop.py
```

I thought this was due to [simpleclip](https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip). 
But I also get this in my magit when I issue `git standup` (using `: standup` from within emacs)

```
  0 git … standup
[31mbe041bb[m - fix sort by name; closes #636 [32m(21 hours ago) [1;34m<darshanime>[m
[31mfa80601[m - change vul order [32m(22 hours ago) [1;34m<darshanime>[m
```

which should be:

```
(venv)  git standup      
be041bb - fix sort by name; closes #636 (21 hours ago) <darshanime>
fa80601 - change vul order (21 hours ago) <darshanime>
```

Comment: The second example seems to be ansi sequences not decoded. Don't know how you issue `git standup`, I assume from shell, so you may try to `(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)`.

Comment: The first example is something different, rather a problem with unicode. Probably the coding-system is wrong, what happens if you use `(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)` or `(prefer-coding-system 'utf-16)` in your `init.el`?

Comment: in the 1st example, I get the garbled content, even after `(prefer-coding-system 'utf-16)` and `(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)`.

Comment: These might help.

    `(set-terminal-coding-system  'utf-8)`
   `(set-keyboard-coding-system  'utf-8)`
    `(set-language-environment    'utf-8)`
    `(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)`
    `(setq locale-coding-system   'utf-8)`
   `(prefer-coding-system        'utf-8)`

Comment: nope, this did not :/
I am using simpleclip to copy from clipboard to emacs please note.

Comment: What OS are you on, and what is the program you are copying from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pasting Text from Clipboard - why ^M instead of linebreaks?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22727/pasting-text-from-clipboard-why-m-instead-of-linebreaks)

Comment: As theldoria mentioned, the second problem is completely different from the first (the `\uXXXX` and `[32m` are two very different forms of garbled text with different causes).  So please clarify your question by focusing on one of the two problems.