# How to change encoding of a string (to fix bad encoding)?

Tags: character-encoding, string

I'm really confused about this issue since it *should* be doable, but i fail to understand it.

I have some file with broken encoding (a pdf file, actually), which I copy some text from. When I paste this text into emacs (or anywhere else) I get sth like "íàïðèìåð", while the correct variant should be cyrillic "например". My buffer encoding is `utf-8` and the broken text has something to do with `cp1251`. My goal is - obviously - to repair this broken encoding and insert it in place of the broken pasted text.

I tried different combinations of `encode-coding-string` and `decode-coding-string` with `utf-8` and `cp1251`, but it gave me some other broken encodings or just a bunch of spaces (that's kinda weird)

Sorry for my messy statement, I just really don't get all this encoding stuff.

---

What I achieved is a (half)solution for the reverse problem: if i write `(encode-coding-string "например" 'cp1251)` and press `C-x C-e`, it prints "íàïðèìåð" to the messages. It's strange, but if I try to *insert* result of this computation into a buffer I get some nonsense yet again... Maybe I miss another aspect of this problem...

Comment: `(decode-coding-string (encode-coding-string "например" 'cp1251) 'cp1251)` gives `#("например" 0 8 (charset windows-1251))`. So you have kind of a round trip and you should try `(decode-coding-string garbage 'cp1251)`. But if you yank in Emacs maybe you should use the `cp1251` coding system for the yank command.

Comment: @Tobias, thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, your solution didn't help. I tried changing things which interact with the clipboard like `set-clipboard-coding-system` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647517/emacs-encoding-of-pasted-text)) and `selection-coding-system` (as described [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/372/character-encoding-when-copying-some-text-from-somewhere-to-emacs-and-saving-to)), but this didn't help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was suspecting the wrong encoding. The following code (using dash)

```
(-> "íàïðèìåð"
    (encode-coding-string 'iso-8859-1)
    (decode-coding-string 'cp1251)
    insert)
```

inserts "например" into a buffer. Though I don't have a clue what's going on)

That's a total victory against these silly encodings, ladies and gentlemen!